# Parse data from a dict with condition - pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

My pandas DataFrame has a few missing and bad values. I'd like to replace / fill this by parse data from a dictionary stored in a pandas series. Here's an example:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Addr': ['123 Street, City, 85036', '234 Street1, City, 85036', '542js'],
                   'Lat': [32.312, 33.312, np.nan],
                   'CL':  [{'street':'134 Street name',
                            'city':'City name',
                            'zip':'85312',
                            'latitude': 34.661056,
                            'longitude': -118.146189},

                           {'street':'134 Street name',
                            'city':'City name',
                            'zip':'85312',
                            'latitude': 34.661056,
                            'longitude': -118.146189},
                          
                           {'street':'134 Str',
                            'city':'phx',
                            'zip':'85312',
                            'latitude': 34.661056,
                            'longitude': -118.146189}]

                  })
```

For rows where `Lat` is `np.nan`, I'd like to parse the data from `CL` column. After filling the data from dict, the 2 columns of the row would look like this:

```
Addr               Lat

134 Str phx 85312  34.661056
```

p.s In reality, the dict is fairly long. So, I'd prefer a way to extract only the values that are needed, in this case `Lat` and `street`, `city` and `zip` which makes up the `Addr` column.

Answer (score 2):

You can normalize the 'CL' column and join the newly created columns to 'Addr' and 'Lat'. Then change the values of `Lat` to 'latitude' where it's `np.nan`:

```
df = df[['Addr', 'Lat']].join(pd.json_normalize(df['CL']))
df.loc[df['Lat'].isna(), 'Lat'] = df.loc[df['Lat'].isna(), 'latitude']
print(df)
```

Output:

```
                       Addr        Lat           street       city    zip   latitude   longitude
0   123 Street, City, 85036  32.312000  134 Street name  City name  85312  34.661056 -118.146189
1  234 Street1, City, 85036  33.312000  134 Street name  City name  85312  34.661056 -118.146189
2                     542js  34.661056          134 Str        phx  85312  34.661056 -118.146189
```

Edit: after reading your comments and edited question, it seems you don't want to build such a huge df, rather work from your dictionnary:

```
your_dict = {'Addr': ['123 Street, City, 85036', '234 Street1, City, 85036', '542js'],
                   'Lat': [32.312, 33.312, np.nan],
                   'CL':  [{'street':'134 Street name',
                            'city':'City name',
                            'zip':'85312',
                            'latitude': 34.661056,
                            'longitude': -118.146189},

                           {'street':'134 Street name',
                            'city':'City name',
                            'zip':'85312',
                            'latitude': 34.661056,
                            'longitude': -118.146189},
                          
                           {'street':'134 Str',
                            'city':'phx',
                            'zip':'85312',
                            'latitude': 34.661056,
                            'longitude': -118.146189}]
                  }

df_lat = pd.Series(your_dict['Lat'])
df_cl = pd.DataFrame(your_dict['CL'])  
print(df_cl.loc[df_lat.isna(), ['latitude', 'street', 'city', 'zip']])
```

That way only rows with 'Lat' initially equal to `np.nan` will be considered:

```
    latitude   street city    zip
2  34.661056  134 Str  phx  85312
```

Comment: Yep, I could use `json_normalize`, however, the dictionary is fairly long, so we only want to parse the variables we're looking for. Would you mind modifying the response keeping this in mind?

Comment: What do you mean? is the processing time too long? Otherwise you could just keep the columns you're interested in: `print(df[['Lat', 'street', 'city', 'zip']])`

Comment: The `length` of the `dict` is very long and has a `nested` structure. `Normalizing` would create additional complexity. I am looking for a way to extract only the `keys` that are required.

Comment: Well I'm not quite sure I grasped all your requirements but I edited my answer. Check it out!

Answer (score 0):

If it's only that one column you want then

```
>>> df['Lat'] = df['Lat'].fillna(pd.DataFrame(df['CL'].tolist())['latitude'])

>>> df
                       Addr        Lat                                                 CL
0   123 Street, City, 85036  32.312000  {'street': '134 Street name', 'city': 'City na...
1  234 Street1, City, 85036  33.312000  {'street': '134 Street name', 'city': 'City na...
2                     542js  34.661056  {'street': '134 Str', 'city': 'phx', 'zip': '8...
```

If the dict is too long for memory then you can parse it with a for loop, convert to df and then fillna

```
keys = []
for i in df['CL'].tolist():
    keys.append({'Lat': i['Lat'], 'street': i['street'],'city': i['city'],'zip': i['zip']})

ddf = pd.DataFrame(keys)
```

Comment: `Addr` is made up of `street`, `city` and `zip` from the dict. Need to replace / fill that as well.

Comment: once you convert the dict to a df you can extract what columns you need

Comment: I added a note at the end of my post - the dict is fairly long and `normalizing` wouldn't be the preferred option.

Comment: I updated for long dict